# Add more words to a text file in C++

Tags: c++, file, text, addition, words

I'm creating a program that writes user inputted words to a text file that already has other words to begin with.  So like this:

```
"words.txt"
apples
oranges
bananas
```

what I wanna do is add other words to the list and then output all the words on the screen.  I wrote a program but it won't input the user specified word.

```
int main(){

    ifstream fin("wordlist.txt");

    if (fin.fail()){
        cerr << "Error opening the file" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    vector<string> wordlist;
    string word;

    string out_word;

    cout << "Please enter a word: ";
    cin >> out_word;

    fin >> out_word;    //Trying to input the user specified word

    //This inputs all the words
    while (!fin.eof()){
        fin >> word;
        wordlist.push_back(word);
    }

    //This outputs all the words on the screen
    for (int i = 0; i < wordlist.size(); i++){
        cout << wordlist[i] << endl;
    }

    fin.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1st of all `while (!fin.eof())` should be `while(fin >> word)`

Comment: What even is this? Was it too difficult to just look up how to write to/from a file. http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Voted to close: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to handle this:

1. Read in the file to the vector
2. Ask the user words and add to the vector
3. Write out all the words of the vector to an out-stream.

Comment: In this particular case i think it would be better to just use a stringstream as they are not trying to access/edit the words again.So just adding them as they are should be enough

Comment: @Jidder: I'm not sure where the stringstream would fit.  I'm just showing that in many cases read-modify-write is the easiest way to work with files instead of editing the file within the code.